# Name of website that looks like an airline schedule?

Tags: website-design

I'm looking for a company website that was talked about on some UX websites a while back. They had this one page where they showed what projects had been completed or were currently in progress and they made it look like an airline schedule.

Each project had something like 'Arriving' or 'Departed' to indicate the project status. And the project status all had a very subtle glow effect.

Thanks!

Sam

Comment: Hi Sam, UX StackExchange isn't really for this kind of questions. But someone answered you (correctly!) before we closed it, so I hope it helped you out ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you're talking about http://culturedcode.com/status/